何で”の”なの？ is this a new grammar point about it?

また、認知されたいじめの件数は、小学校が58万8930件、中学校が12万2703件、高校が1万7611件、特別支援学校が3324件のあわせて73万2568件で、前の年度よりも5万件余り増えて過去最多となりました。

Why is there a の after 3324件?
I know that の can nominalise and is used for possession, but in this case I don’t think it’s both, so anyone that knows why please help.
I’m 100 percent confident that it isn’t the が that’s get turned into の in subordinative sentence because there isn’t a noun after it, it’s あわせて and it can’t be 73万 because it’s in て form (合わせて) and it means that the sentence can be a logical clause on its own, so it needs to have a noun before the て.
That’s all I got, and if possible, I would like you guys to respond with Cure Dolly’s explanation because I’m familiar with her reasons.

Alright, so after a day of thinking, I finally got it. Really needed some time thinking about it and finally connected the points that the apposition の has the same effect as the Chinese 的. Finally got the hang of it. Really appreciate both of you guys

This not a possessive marker, nor a subject marker, nor a nominalizer, but の as an apposition marker. It roughly means "..., which is ～". See:

「の」usage in「１時間前の午前８時半」
What's the difference between 日本人の学生 and 日本の学生 ?
Confusing use of の

In your sentence, "小学校が58万8930件...特別支援学校が3324件" is equivalent to "あわせて73万2568件 (732,568 cases in total)".
Similar use of の:

最終得点は田中さんが25点の1位、鈴木さんが18点の2位でした。
The final scores were: Tanaka-san in first place with 25 points, and Suzuki-san in second place with 18 points.


Okay, first time ever hearing apposition, don’t even know what it means but I will check it out when I have time. Thank you for responding. Oh and also where did you even learn this “apposition” thing, did you learn it from a teacher or what cause I want to hear their thoughts on it.

@JackyPlays My native language is Japanese, and I first learned the concept of 同格 while learning how to read English sentences like these. I learned the English term "apposition" much later, after starting to visit this site.

As far as I'm aware, while a dictionary can list many nuances, there a fundamentally only two kinds of の: the nominalizing kind and the descriptive kind. This can't be nominalizing, since there's no verb or adjective form to nominalize - but also because a nominalizing の wouldn't be followed by another noun (but by a particle or a copula). あわせて73万2568件 is a noun (well, the counted noun 73万2568件 described by an adverb あわせて; so, "the altogether 732,568 cases"), and we have noun phrases before it; thus those noun phrases are some kind of description.
XのY as a description is much broader than just "possessive/genitive". The pattern followed here is that the X and Y are two ways of referring to the same thing (as naruto describes, the equivalent of apposition in English: the の here stands for something like "which is" in English, except it can't generally be elided). Indeed, 58万8930, 12万2703, 1万7611 and 3324 sum to 73万2568; therefore, those groups of 件 can collectively be referring to the same thing as the あわせて73万2568件 (especially considering the meaning of あわせて).
As a simpler example, a lyric from a well known Vocaloid song:
あなただけのアテンダントの私
The first の is in a rough sense possessive: アテンダントの私 doesn't belong to あなた(だけ), but is "for" you (as the listener). The second can be taken as appositive (though this overlaps with a sense I think of more as "categorizing"): アテンダント and 私 describe the same person (the singer). "I, who belong to exclusively your attendant" is nonsense; "I, who am an attendant just for you" is the intended meaning.

So when do we know that it’s acting as an apposition? Are there any common patterns they appear in?

Much like I was told when I posted that other question in 2011: Japanese may be considerably more regular than English on average, but it's still a real-world language that evolved over time, and not something that was consciously designed to be precise. Many things will be ambiguous on a purely syntactic level and you need to use common sense to parse them. That said, my perception is that these different uses don't feel as distinct in native Japanese thought as they do in English thought,.
